# What is the best practice for dealing with a failed dynamic import in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

I use Webpack dynamic imports to split my bundle. In particular, I often use it with `React.lazy` like so

```
const Component = React.lazy(() =>
  import(/* webpackPreload: true, webpackChunkName: "component" */ 'path/to/component')
)
// Some time later
<Suspense fallback={<div />}>
  <Component />
</Suspense>
```

It all works great and helped me reduce the size of my bundle a lot. However, sometimes, the code fails to download on user side and the user gets an error like so `Loading chunk 1 failed`.

What are the best practices for dealing with such dynamic import errors? I'm thinking about writing a retry function, but I feel like I must be re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: I do not use React - but when this happens I display an error and let the user reload. Not perfect. In the react world there seems to be https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#error-boundaries to handle errors - but there is nothing about reloading/retry.

Comment: Yep, I did read that and exactly as you say – it talks about how to handle the error and show it to the user gracefully, but nothing about how to make sure it gets loaded eventually.